# Join multiple values from one column, selected from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, join

Given these simplified multiple choice tables where sometimes more than one answer is correct:

```
STUDENT_ANSWERS
AnswerID | StudentID | QuestionID | Answers
-------------------------------------------
       1 |         1 |          1 | C,D

QUESTION_ANSWERS
QuestionID | Answer | Text
-------------------------------------------------
         1 |      A | This is answer A
         1 |      B | B could also be correct
         1 |      C | Maybe it's C?
         1 |      D | Definitely D!
```

How do I do a select which translates the answers to their descriptions?

My start:

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT_ANSWERS sa
LEFT OUTER JOIN QUESTION_ANSWERS qa ON qa.Answer IN sa.Answers???
 -- Doesn't seem to work as IN requires a format of ('C','D') while I have 'C,D'
```

Desired output:

```
AnswerID | StudentID | QuestionID | AnswerDescriptions
-------------------------------------------
       1 |         1 |          1 | Maybe it's C?,Definitely D!
```

So the descriptions simply have to replace the codes instead of getting a single line for each answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the structure of table `STUDENT_ANSWERS`. It should have one row per answer:

```
AnswerID | StudentID | QuestionID | Answer
-------------------------------------------
       1 |         1 |          1 | C
       2 |         1 |          1 | D
```

---

Now, assuming you can't do anything to change (read: fix) this, you can fudge it with appending a comma and using LIKE:

```
select *
from STUDENT_ANSWERS a
join QUESTION_ANSWERS q on ',' + a.Answers + ',' like '%,' + q.Answer + ',%'
    and a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25ba6/2)

Note this *assumes you will never ever have the text `,` in `QUESTION_ANSWERS.Answer`*. It will also never be able to use an index, so it's going to be slower than slow.

And if you *absolutely must* format this in the database to be one line, you can use `STUFF` and the `FOR XML PATH('')` trick to concatenate the resulting rows.

Comment: This is close, but my real case has codes that look alike instead of Answers, like A and AA and it selects them both if the answer has A but not AA.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a564f/1, and it's the reason we have to go through the trouble of concatenating all those commas.

Answer (score 1):

This is full working example using only `T-SQL` statements. I will recommend to you to create separate function for splitting `CSV` that returns row set. Also, if you are working with huge amount of data, you may want to create a `CLR` function for splitting the values. Take a look to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx) (there is everything you need).

```
DECLARE @StudentAnswers TABLE
(
     [AnswerID] INT
    ,[StudentID] INT
    ,[QuestionID] INT
    ,[Answers] VARCHAR(256)
);

DECLARE @QuestionAnswers TABLE
(
     [QuestionID] INT
    ,[Answer] CHAR
    ,[Text] VARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO @StudentAnswers ([AnswerID], [StudentID], [QuestionID], [Answers])
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'C,D')
      ,(2, 2, 1, 'A');

 INSERT INTO @QuestionAnswers ([QuestionID], [Answer], [Text])
 VALUES  (1, 'A', 'This is answer A')
        ,(1, 'B', 'B could also be correct')
        ,(1, 'C', 'Maybe it''s C?')
        ,(1, 'D', 'Definitely D!');

SELECT SA.[AnswerID]
      ,SA.[StudentID]
      ,SA.[QuestionID]
      ,T.c.value('.', 'CHAR')
      ,QA.[Text]
FROM @StudentAnswers SA
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CAST('<i>' + REPLACE([Answers], ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML) Answers
) DS
CROSS APPLY DS.Answers.nodes('i') T(c)
INNER JOIN @QuestionAnswers QA
    ON SA.[QuestionID] = QA.[QuestionID]
    AND T.c.value('.', 'CHAR') = QA.[Answer];
```

Comment: Cute use of XML and SQL Server's ability to select into it. Not sure it performs any better than my solution, but it's much more readable. Especially if you use a more descriptive tag than `<i>` and refactor `T(c)` into a function/view.

Comment: Truly, encapsulating the splitting functionality in separate function is preferable. In my practice, using `CLR` function for splitting is always the fastest way (also, you can write separate functions depending on what you are returning - one character or many). I am not sure how good the `JOIN` with `LIKE` clause will act when large tables and `CSV` strings are used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select answerid,studentid,a.QuestionID,group_concat(b.text) from student_answers a left join QUESTION_ANSWERS b on b.questionid= a.questionid and  FIND_IN_SET(b.Answer, a.Answers)
group by a.questionid
```

Definitely it works.

Comment: The questions is tagged with `TSQL` tag which means it is related to `Microsoft SQL Server`, not `mySQL`

Answer (score 0):

I've stuck with the same question. But only for MariaDB.

```
select a.names, second,
  group_concat(second order by locate(concat('/', b.names, '/'), concat('/',a.names,'/')) asc)
from mytable a
join temp b on concat('/',a.names,'/') like concat('%/', b.names, '/%')
group by a.names
```

Look at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d1pgw-dw)

It was:

[image]

And become:

[image]

As you can see, we saved an order of names.

I hope, it will help someone!